# What does a $-$ signify in formula for combinations

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Hardy and wright define the following

$$\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m(m-1)(m-2)..(m-n+1)}{n!} \; ... (1)$$
$$\binom{-m}{n} = (-1)^n \;\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)..(m+n-1)}{n!} \; ...(2)$$

then they say $$\binom{-m}{n} = (-1)^n\binom{m+n-1}{n} \; ...(3)$$

Eq. $(3)$ does not make sense to me. How is it obtained ? ( they don't give any constraint on $m,n$, as to which is bigger or smaller ).

Comment: $n$ is any non-negative integer. $m$ is any number .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you originally stated $(2)$ and $(3)$ incorrectly. Assuming that you’re referring to their Theorem $73$, they should read

$$\binom{-m}n=(-1)^n\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)\ldots(m+n-1)}{n!}\tag{2a}$$

and

$$\binom{-m}n=(-1)^n\binom{m+n-1}{n}\;,\tag{3a}$$

respectively (as they now do). Observe that $(1)$ says that

$$\binom{m+n-1}{n}=\frac{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)\ldots(m)}{n!}\;:$$

there are $n$ factors in the numerator, counting down from $m+n-1$ to $m$. These are the same $n$ factors that appear in the numerator of $(2\text{a})$ in the opposite order, so $3\text{a}$ is just a restatement of $2\text{a}$.

Comment: Thanks! Corrected my mistake.

Comment: @sasha: You’re welcome!